# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform. How to handle such errors?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I had a doubt like how to handle field does not exists situation like suppose i have released my app and in future updates i added a new field in doc then how can i handle if field does not exists.

For example, in shared preferences we use `??`to handle data existence with the specified key value.

```
int val=prefs.getInt("myKey")??0;
```

as you can see that above code will set value of val to 0 if there's no value associated with the key- myKey. Similarly i would like to know is there any way of doing it for firestore document fields.

MyCode:-

```
class UserModel
{
  final String? id;
  final String? username;
  final String? email;

  UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.email,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc)
  {
    return UserModel(
      id: doc['id'],
      username: doc['username'],//suppose the username does not exist in the field then how can i assign the value "User" to the username?
      email: doc['email'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem when developing an app which use Firebase. If you add a field after there is already a data and if you try to get new field in dart, you are getting this error. I think the only solution is deleting all the old data which doesn't have new field. Or put this new field to all of your old data. It's kinda annoying. So make sure that you have to add all possible field in the beginning.

Unfortunately, you can't use like `int val=prefs.getInt("myKey")??0;` because it isn't even null.

Comment: I understand it's a good practice to have all the fields in the beginning but we don't know about the future updates. So, just wanted to know a way to handle such things.